# Private network issues with docker

Tags: docker

I'm having trouble connecting to MongoDB on the docker host. I'm not sure what the problem is but my current docker container should be able to connect with a non-docker MongoDB instance.

My host has 2 network interfaces which are eth0 with an outbound IP and eth1 with a private lan ip 192.168.100.200. Is there any way to connect to the host without doing --net=host?

Comment: What error do you get?  Can you ping from a container to the address?  Any firewall (e.g. ufw) running?

Comment: Are you sure mongodb is listening on 192.168.100.200:27017 ?

Run netstat -nap --tcp | grep LISTEN on the host.  Make sure it's listening.  The docker instance should be able to ping 192.168.100.200 and connect to mongo on that interface unless your networking setup is screwy.

Comment: I don't get an error message, I tried to stop the iptables firewall but it doesn't matter. I tried a clean centos image to try to ping and connect to the mongodb host.

Comment: It listens on all IP addresses:
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:27017               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      31494/mongod

Comment: OK nevermind... Turns out it's the firewall after all :S

Answer (score 0):

Can you enter in your MongoDB using nsenter or docker exec, and issue some commands such as

```
ip all
```

using

```
nsenter
```

from https://github.com/jpetazzo/nsenter
or

```
docker exec
```

if you have a recent version of docker

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by this. The MongoDB instance is one installed directly on the host server, and it has to remain there because it is used by other projects/software as well. The MongoDB instance works fine for everything else except for the fact that I can't reach it from inside the container

Comment: OK nevermind... Turns out it's the firewall after all :S Sorry! Thanks for helping!